# GNU Parallel timeout for process

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I want to use GNU Parallel for this command:

```
seq -w 30 | parallel -k -j6 java -javaagent:build/libs/pddl4j-3.1.0.jar -server -Xms8048m -Xmx8048m fr.uga.pddl4j.planners.hsp.HSP -o pddl/benchmarks_STRIPS/benchmarks_STRIPS/ipc1/movie/domain.pddl -f pddl/benchmarks_STRIPS/benchmarks_STRIPS/ipc1/movie/p{}.pddl -i 8 '>>' AstarMovie.txt
```

I have a timeout of 600 seconds in the java program but parallel doesn't execute it. Processes can run for 2, 3, 4 or more hours and never stop.

I tried this command based on the GNU tutorial online, but it doesn't work either:

```
seq -w 30 | parallel -k --timeout 600000 -j6 java -javaagent:build/libs/pddl4j-3.1.0.jar -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m fr.uga.pddl4j.planners.hsp.HSP -o pddl/benchmarks_STRIPS/benchmarks_STRIPS/ipc1/movie/domain.pddl -f pddl/benchmarks_STRIPS/benchmarks_STRIPS/ipc1/movie/p{}.pddl -i 8 '>>' AstarMovie.txt
```

I saw in the tutorial that GNU Parallel uses milliseconds - so 600000 is 10 minutes which is what I need but after 12 minutes the process was still running. I need 6 processes to run at once for a maximum of 10 minutes each.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

EDIT:
Why do people feel the need to edit posts for small changes like '600seconds' to '600 seconds'? Stop doing it for karma..

Comment: What do you mean "GNU Parallel doesn't respect your timeout"? If your program stops of its own accord after 10 minutes how can GNU Parallel keep it running?

Comment: The GNU Parallel manpage says the `--timeout` value is in seconds.

Comment: In my java program I have a timeout set of 600seconds to complete a task. When using GNU parallel the process will go over this timeout and continue trying to solve a problem

Comment: "--timeout val

    Time out for command. If the command runs for longer than val seconds it will get killed with SIGTERM, followed by SIGTERM 200 ms later, followed by SIGKILL 200 ms later.

    If val is followed by a % then the timeout will dynamically be computed as a percentage of the median average runtime. Only values > 100% will make sense."
Saw this on the tutorial page and thought it used milliseconds

Comment: No, it says *"If the command runs for longer than val seconds"*.

Comment: I understand but thought the general format for setting a timeout was in milliseconds because of that. Stupid mistake, I know, but under that section it didn't specify if it was seconds or not so I assumed it was milliseconds. Will test it now with your advice

Comment: Just try this... `time parallel --timeout 10 sleep {} ::: 15`

Comment: Thanks, will test it now

Comment: I put it as an answer to keep the unanswered question total down and so all can see it clearly without having to wade through comments.

Comment: Yeah it worked perfectly with your command in the answer and with timeout--600 (10mins). Really appreciate your help, saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The timeout for **GNU Parallel** is given in seconds, not milliseconds. You can test it with this snippet which waits for 15 seconds but with a timeout that cuts it off after 10 seconds:

```
time parallel --timeout 10 sleep {} ::: 15

real    0m10.961s
user    0m0.071s
sys     0m0.038s
```